# PHP return array or -1

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to have something like this:

```
if (($sqlResult = returnArrayAfterSQLResult(...)) != -1) {
  getRow($sqlResult);
  /* ... */
} else {
  /* handling error */
}
```

Everything is working well, but I know that is not 100% correct that I am returning mysqli array if it is ok or -1 if there is a problem. And I also get notice from server: Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in ...

So what do you think about ?

Comment: If you get this notice, then it's NOT working well.

Comment: Try using `!==` rather than `!=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning different data types from a function is totally OK (lots of built-in functions do it) and one of the nice things that PHP allows. It *is* unusual to return resource or integer; resource/`false` or resource/`null` are much more common options and ones you should consider.

That said, the notice from your code is due to the fact that the comparison is made with `!=`. If you don't change the error return type, use `!==` instead:

```
if (($sqlResult = returnArrayAfterSQLResult(...)) !== -1)
```

This will prevent PHP from trying to convert the resource to an integer.

Comment: Yes, I like PHP because with this, the code can be much more simple. Thank you for hints. I did not know about !==, but still I think that I change it to return false.

Answer (score 0):

PHP isnt typesafe. So you need to cast your return to an int, or rethink what values you are returning. E.g. the result object or false.